# Ubuntu 12.10 sometimes crashes when booting

Tags: 12.10, boot

I sometimes (several times a week) experience a complete crash when booting up Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit). Not only GUI fails to load, even hitting Ctrl + Alt + F1 does nothing, and I have to power off the machine.

In some cases this has repeated for several times, until I have selected advanced options and choose an older kernel. After this the newest also boots normally for a while.